# Unpacking a pandas dataframe column that contains a list of dictionaries into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `new_df` that has one column, which contains a list of dictionaries, with some rows `NaN`.

```
new_df
                                                            0
    0                                                 NaN
    1                                                 NaN
    2   [{'start_time': '09:16:44', 'e...
    3   [{'start_time': '09:36:44', 'e...
    4   [{'start_time': '09:46:44', 'e...
    5   [{'start_time': '09:48:44', 'e...
    6   [{'start_time': '09:55:44', 'e...
    7   [{'start_time': '09:59:44', 'e...
    8   [{'start_time': '10:50:22', 'e...
    9   [{'start_time': '11:30:22', 'e...
    10  [{'start_time': '11:35:22', 'e...
    11  [{'start_time': '12:50:22', 'e...
    12                                                NaN
    13                                                NaN
```

When a row contains a list containing a dictionary it is in this format:

```
[{'start_time': '09:16:44', 'end_time': '9:36:44', 'job_id': '123456'}]
```

I need to unpack the dictionary in each list/row in `new_df` into new columns and apply these new columns to another dataframe.

The problem I am having is preserving the index of `new_df` as it is needed to correctly apply the new column data to the other dataframe.

I can unpack the lists and create new columns from the dictionary values, but when I apply the new columns, they apply to `row[0]` instead of `row[2]` in this case. I lose the rows at the beginning and end where the row values are `NaN`.

```
add_df = pd.DataFrame(list(new_df[0]))
```

Produces

```
  start_time   end_time   job_id  
0  09:16:44  09:36:44     123456
1  09:36:44  09:46:44     123457
2  09:46:44  09:48:44     123458
3  09:48:44  09:59:59     123459
      ...      ...          ...
8  11:35:22  12:45:00     123460
9  12:50:22  13:00:00     123461
```

What I **need** is to preserve the indexes like shown below, the indexes from `new_df` that holds the lists of dictionaries:

```
      start_time   end_time   job_id  
    0    NaN        NaN         NaN
    1    NaN        NaN         NaN
    2  09:16:44  09:36:44     123456
    3  09:36:44  09:46:44     123457
    4  09:46:44  09:48:44     123458
    5  09:48:44  09:59:59     123459
          ...      ...          ...
   10  11:35:22  12:45:00     123460
   11  12:50:22  13:00:00     123461
   12    NaN        NaN         NaN
   13    NaN        NaN         NaN
```

How can I preserve the index to and have the leading and trailing `NaN` rows?

Comment: can you add `df.head().to_dict()` in the question for us to see the exact format of you data. otherwise, if how you create add_df works for you, you can specify the index like `pd.DataFrame(list(df[0]), index=df.index[df[0].notna()])`

Comment: I've updated the post.  Your comment made me realize I was unclear on what my desired end result is.  I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it throws `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14, 1), indices imply (10, 1)`

Comment: I still can't reproduce exactly the same behavior than you, but try with dropna and then reindex with original index  `pd.DataFrame(list(df[0].dropna()), index=df.index[df[0].notna()]).reindex(df.index)`

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by @Ben.T made me think of what I was trying to accomplish.

I was creating a dataframe from a series that is a list of dictionaries.  Why was I peeling off this new dataframe column by column, when I could apply the new dataframe to the existing dataframe on the column axis?

My solution:

```
# Creates df but removes the NaN elements
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(orig_df[0]).dropna())   

# Get the orig_df indexes of non-NaN rows to apply to the new df
new_ndx = new_df.index[orig_df[0].notna()]

# Reset index and give new indexes that will line up
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df = new_df.set_index(new_ndx)

# Now apply the new_df to the orig_df
orig_df= pd.concat([orig_df, new_df ], axis=1)
```

Is there maybe a more pythonic way to accomplish this...?